# develop ble win32 application on windows 7

Tags: winapi, bluetooth

I want to develop an activex control running on windows 7,which use bluetooth 4.0(ble)  to communicate with portable devices.It seems that only windowd 8.1 can support ble development.So how can i  develop such  ocx running on windows 7 ?

Answer (score 1):

As documented under [Bluetooth Low Energy Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj159880.aspx):

> Windows 8 introduces support for the Bluetooth Low Energy technology.

Prior to Windows 8, you cannot use Bluetooth Low Energy, irrespective of whether this is for an ActiveX control or any other implementation. You need Windows 8 to use the Bluetooth Low Energy technology.